# How to have Ansible string package not installed

Tags: loops, ansible

Can't seem to get my second play to catch the package and print that it is not installed. Here is my playbook:

```
---
- hosts: all
  vars:
    packages:
      - httpd
      - unzip
      - yum
      - nmap
  tasks:
    - name: getting package facts
      package_facts:
        manager: auto
    - name: Check whether our packages are installed
      debug:
        msg: "{{ ansible_facts.packages[item][0].name }} {{ ansible_facts.packages[item][0].version }}"
      loop: "{{ packages }}"
      register: pkgcheck

    - name: Display packages not installed
      debug:
        msg: "{{ pkgcheck }} is not installed"
      when: '"pkgcheck" is not defined'
      loop: "{{ packages }}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use filter [difference](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/devel/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#selecting-from-sets-or-lists-set-theory), e.g.

```yaml
  pkg_not_installed: "{{ packages|difference(ansible_facts.packages.keys()) }}"
```

---

For example, use the list in the loop

```yaml
    - name: Display packages not installed
      debug:
        msg: "{{ item }} is not installed"
      loop: "{{ packages|difference(ansible_facts.packages.keys()) }}"
```

---

Q: **"*Is there a way to get both tasks to print my list of installed and not installed?*"**

A: Use [intersect](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/devel/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#selecting-from-sets-or-lists-set-theory) to print installed packages, e.g.

```yaml
    - name: Display installed packages
      debug:
        msg: "{{ item }} is installed"
      loop: "{{ packages|intersect(ansible_facts.packages.keys()) }}"
```

Comment: where do I put pkg_not_installed in my playbook ?

Comment: I've added an example. HTH.

Comment: Thank you I was confused  I replaced my original task                                                                    "- name: Check whether our packages are installed "  with your suggestion " - name: Display packages not installed " and I was able to get debug to msg what is not installed from my list. Is there a way to get both tasks to print my list of installed and not installed ?

Comment: Sure. Use `intersect`. I've updated the answer.